# Posting data return error with reqres API

Tags: javascript, rest

I am using [reqres](https://reqres.in/) API to do a login but it is 400 error which says

```
{
    "error": "Missing email or username"
}
```

I tried with postman but same error, this is my URL string from postman

```
https://reqres.in/api/login?email=eve.holt@reqres.in&password=cityslicka
```

and I am using the following in JS

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    const myData = 'email=eve.holt@reqres.in&password=cityslicka'
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/login", {
        method: 'post',
        headers : {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"} ,
        body: {
            myData
        },
    })
})
```

Comment: You are sending a `POST` request with no data. You are attempting to send data in the URL query string but that is for `GET` requests, not `POST`.

Comment: I suggest you read about the differences between POST and GET. Specifically how the differ in sending data.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I updated my code. still same issue.

Comment: @Nofel You are getting closer. The format of the body is different than the format for URL params. Again, I suggest you read more about POST and how to format it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice any good link? I m not fan of MDN

Comment: Look at the examples in the `reqres` document you linked.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are making a POST request, you need to send the data in the body of the request instead of in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was doing it wrong but got it working after following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oive66jrwBs&ab_channel=TraversyMedia), correct (but hardcoded) code is as follows

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/login", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers : {"Content-Type": "application/json"} ,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "email":"eve.holt@reqres.in",
            "password":"cityslicka"
        })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
})
```

Thanks to @Code-Apprentice for pointers

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Note that the call to `JSON.stringify()` is not needed. You can just use the JavaScript object directly with `data` instead of `body`.